# Determine custom section header frame when tableView mode grouped

Tags: ios, uitableview

I provide a custom section header via the tableView's delegate method. It works fine in plane mode but I can't figure out the correct margin in grouped style.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to  make the section header aligned with the tableView cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested in every flavor but a good starting point.
In
 `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
pass the tableView.style parameter to your own method providing the header.
Create a view a frame like
 `CGRect(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(tableView.frame)`
but add a subview with a frame
`CGRectInset(frame, 30,0)`
if you have a grouped tableView style. Set a the autoresizingMask to flexible width and it works.

Slightly modified in a way that I had to give an additional parameter to the creation method for the SectionHeaderView as the margin is different for presentationStyle FullScreen and Formsheet.

```
        CGFloat margin = 0;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        margin = style == UITableViewStyleGrouped ? modalStyle == UIModalPresentationFormSheet ? 28 : 38 : 0;
    }
    else {
        margin = style == UITableViewStyleGrouped ? 5 : 0;
    }

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(frame, margin, 0)];
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom label and adjust its frame accordingly.
For eg.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aTableView.tableHeaderView.frame];


 UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(//set frame of the label as you want)];

[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: size:]];

[label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];

[label setShadowColor:[UIColor redColor];

label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

if(section==0)

{

 [label setText://set your section0 title];

 }

else if(section ==1)

{

[label setText://set your section1 title];

 }

[view addSubview:label];

[label release];

 return [view autorelease];
}

Hope this helps :)
```